# VBA - Copy and paste in last workday

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to copy some values of a range to a specific row (Excel).
The values are in range B2:F2
These values should be copied in the row for yesterday, but just if this day were a workday. If today is Monday, the values should be copied to the row of Friday.

I have date-values in A2:A3500 in the format "dd.mm.yyyy". The values should be copied into Bx:Fx.

How can be this done?

I have already tried, but it doesn't work....

```
Dim sv, sq, k As Long, zl
With Sheets("tblGeneral")
sv = .Cells(6, 1).CurrentRegion.Resize(, 6)
sq = .Cells(2, 2).Resize(, 5)
zl = Application.Match(CLng(Date), .Columns(1), 0)
  If Not IsError(zl) Then
       For k = 2 To 6
         sv(zl - 7, k) = sq(1, k - 1)
       Next k
     .Cells(6, 1).CurrentRegion.Resize(, 6) = sv
  End If

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rTarget As Range
    Dim rCopy As Range
    Dim dtCompare As Date
    Dim dtTarget As Date
    Dim sDateFormat As String

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("tblGeneral")
    Set rCopy = ws.Range("B2:F2")
    dtCompare = Date
    sDateFormat = ws.Range("A2").NumberFormat

    Select Case Format(dtCompare, "ddd")
        Case "Mon": dtTarget = dtCompare - 3
        Case "Sun": dtTarget = dtCompare - 2
        Case Else:  dtTarget = dtCompare - 1
    End Select

    Set rTarget = ws.Columns("A").Find(Format(dtTarget, sDateFormat), , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rTarget Is Nothing Then
        rTarget.Offset(, 1).Resize(rCopy.Rows.Count, rCopy.Columns.Count).Value = rCopy.Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Target date [" & Format(dtTarget, sDateFormat) & "] not found.", , "Error"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey tigeravater, thanks! Unfortunately it is not working. Here you can finde a simple example of the structure: https://ufile.io/s5z9qtwv

Comment: Hey tigeravater, do you have any idea?

Comment: @joshua1990 Unfortunately I can't access the link you posted.  Best recommendation is to edit your original question to provide sample data.  I'll also need to you elaborate regarding "it is not working."  Are you getting an error? If so, what's the error and on what line?  If it's not erroring, are you getting unexpected or incorrect results?  If that's the case, when you provide sample data, please point out the unexpected/incorrect results and specify what the correct, expected results would be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is an alternative link : https://gofile.io/?c=hUSxnG . No, I'dont get an error - it is just not working. I go throw F8 but I can't see the failure/ mistake...